# How to assert true and false in single parameterized test method

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

I am new to Unit Testing and quite confusing about testing true or false result returned from method rely on parameter. I am currently using NUnit and MoQ, below is my code. Test will run three times with value A, B, C for each time respectively.

```
[Test]
    public void IFoo_Return_True_With_A_As_Input([Values("A", "B", "C")]string value){
        var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
        // setup
        mock.Setup(foo => foo.DoSomething("A")).Returns(true);

        // Arrage
        Func<string, bool> action = (_) => mock.Object.DoSomething(_);

        // Act
        bool result = action(value);

        // Assert
        Assert.That(result, /* ??? */);
    }
```

I have a method which receives a value through parameter *IFoo.DoSomething* and it will return **true** if the value of parameter is *A*, otherwise it will return **false**. I do not know how to present this kind of test in single test.

I thought I can not use multiple assertions(I mean one assert for true and other for false) because result will be evaluated to true or false per test. I thought I could use *TestCase* with *ExpectedResult* OR *Assume* before Assert OR write two test(one for A value and other for other values) but I would like to know whether we have any sophisticated ways to achieve kind this test.

My expectation would be three test will passed with true or false evaluated rely on supplied value in single test. Please advise me if I am not going on the right track about Unit Test.

The setup of mock is the way I present the implementation of *IFoo.DoSomething* method. Its logic is return true if value is A and false if otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you actually trying to test here? That a mock you've set up, that you have complete control over, will conditionally return true or false?

Your current setup will do that - `.DoSomething("A")` will return true and all other string values fired into `DoSomething` will return a default bool (false). If you don't setup a method it'll return the default value of the return type.

You could assert this for the cases you've specified in a single assert:

```
Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(value.Equals("A")))
```

... but I'm not sure why you'd do that. You're not testing your code, you're testing Moq/your mock setup.

Generally I'd expect a unit test to test a concrete implementation (`Foo` for example). Any dependencies that `Foo` needs (`IBar` for example) would be mocked.

Say you had a concrete implementation `Foo` that implements `IFoo.DoSomething(string)`. You'd write 2 tests methods, something like the following:

```
public void DoSomething_A_ReturnsTrue()
```

and

```
public void DoSomething_NotA_ReturnsFalse()
```

Each one would do whatever setup was required to create an instance of `Foo`, invoke `DoSomething` with the value that matches the test description, and finally a single assert that matches the expected test result (true or false).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I basically want to know how to write a test for a function in which return true or false in specific case. Please see my update above.

Comment: The assert in my answer will do the case you're asking about. However it is better practice to write separate unit tests for the 2 scenarios your method handles.

Comment: No, Sorry for not clear the question. I expect to test the result of a method DoSomething( in this case it is boolean) using single test. In your answer it will work if result is "string", I can write a test case like these [TestCase("A", ExpectedResult = true)] - [TestCase("B", ExpectedResult = false)] - [TestCase("C", ExpectedResult = false)] but i want to write test in single test method using assert. I want to know is there any way to do this with this kind of test.

Comment: No, the assert is written with result being a boolean. `value.Equals("A")` resolves to true or false depending on what the value is (true if value is "A", false if value is any other string), `Is.EqualTo(value.Equals("A"))` is basically saying `Is.EqualTo(true)` for "A" and `Is.EqualTo(false)` for any other string.

Comment: Oh, you open my mind :). *value.Equals("A")* inside EqualTo is exactly what i want thank you. Will devote myself more in unit testing, so cool.